# Email Validation php

Tags: php, validation, email

Basicly i need to validate the email with it containing exact letters. Lets say my college has a student with id x12627353@student.ncirl.ie , i want the validation to force the student to enter x at the start of the email, then 8 random numbers of their student card and for last to have the validation requiring @student.ncirl.ie. Other wise not allowing the students to register and login into the website.

Code i have is:

```
 if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $error = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
    } else {
        // check email exist or not
        $query = "SELECT userEmail FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count!=0){
            $error = true;
            $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";
        }
    }
```

I was thinking to do it this way: `\b[x0-9._%+-]+@student.ncirl.ie\b` but im just a beginner in php and im not able to implement it. If anyone would be able, could u give me a hand by creating a sample code ? Or a brief description. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to dig into [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

> Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.

For example :

```
$email = "x12627353@student.ncirl.ie";
$result = preg_match('/^x[\d]{8}@student\.ncirl\.ie$/', $email);

if ($result) {
    ...
    do some stuff
    ...
}
```

The test of the regular expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eA7Q07/3).

The explanations :

> **^** asserts position at start of the string
>
> **x** matches the character x literally (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below :
>
> **[\d]{8}**
>
> **{8}** Quantifier — Matches exactly 8 times
>
> **\d** matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>
> **@student** matches the characters @student literally (case sensitive)
>
> **.** matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
>
> **ncirl** matches the characters ncirl literally (case sensitive)
>
> **.** matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
>
> **ie** matches the characters ie literally (case sensitive)
>
> **$** asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line
>   terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that really helped ! :)