# validation, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, validation, email

So basiclly i just want this code below:

```
    //basic email validation
    if(!eregi('^x[\d]{8}@student\.ncirl\.ie$', $email)){
        // Return Error - Invalid Email
        $error = true;
        $emailError = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';
    }
    if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $error = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
    } else {
        // check email exist or not
        $query = "SELECT userEmail FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count!=0){
            $error = true;
            $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";
        }
    }
```

To validate the email if it is exactly similar to email - "x14332684@student.ncirl.ie" , i want it to keep the x at the start, have 8 random numbers after x and as it is everything after @. Only numbers to be random and the rest should be a "must". I just cant get it to validate the email like i want, using this code tells me pernament "The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.". Can anyone edit the code for me and point out what am i doing wrong in it? Thank you.

Comment: Best to use preg_match, eregi has been removed in PHP 7

Comment: The pattern does work. http://regexr.com/3ejho

Comment: Devon are you able to edit my code to show me how to do it? Im a beginner in php and im not able to code it off. Thank you for your answers anyways Devon and Phiter :)

Comment: @DawidTrojanowski, it's the same thing, basically. Just replace eregi with preg_match. (in your case)

Comment: The documentation is quite straight forward: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Use PDO instead of mysql_* !

Comment: Didn't I solve your Question two days ago ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438322/email-validation-php/40438384#40438384

Comment: @AdrienLeber that made me lol a bit.  Dawid, what are you doing here with eregi then?

Comment: Secondly you need to use `elseif` at `filter_var` stage. Because irrespective of your pattern match stage, the else part will execute when a user enter a valid email pattern.

Comment: Why have the `filter_var()` at all, since the regex already validates the string to match a specific pattern?

Comment: @AdrienLeber yea u did ans my question and all but when i implemented it and i was still missing something and could not put it right, when i was puting preg_match i was getting all the emails to go through because i  was forgetting " ! ".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, i have just edited the code and removed the filter_var(), i was using that because my preg/eregi wasent working. Thank you all for your help and sorry for that retarded post!!!!

Comment: Ok, I understand. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with preg_match.  One thing you need to do is wrap the pattern with delimiters, most use `/` like:

```
if(!preg_match('/^x[\d]{8}@student\.ncirl\.ie$/', $email)){
    // Return Error - Invalid Email
    $error = true;
    $emailError = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Oh god i was trying to use preg_match but i never had put "!" before it, i was wondering why it is letting through all of the passwords! Sorry for this post... and thank you for the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this site: http://www.phpliveregex.com/ for future **preg_matche**s

Comment: Post this as a comment.  This isn't an answer.